# No muestra calculos de porcentaje

Tags: c#

Me estoy inciando en C# y tengo un problema que no puedo resolver...

Necesito sacar el procentaje de venta de tres productos (1,2,3) del total.

Hago la operaciones correspondientes y me devuele en pantalla un valor 0 en cada una de las operaciones. Aun cambiando el calculo me devuelve el mismo valor.

Que podra ser ?

Aqui adjunto el codigo

Saludos

```
        int codigo = 1;
        double prom = 0;
        int total = 0;
        int contadorgral = 0;
        int contador1 = 0;
        int contador2 = 0;
        int contador3 = 0;

        int acumulador1 = 0;

        while (codigo != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingresar codigo: ");
            Console.WriteLine("(Presione 0 para finalizar la venta)");
            codigo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (codigo == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ud compro producto 1");
                total = total + 100;
                //Sumamos las ventas del producto 1 con sus totales
                contador1 = contador1 + 1;
                acumulador1 = acumulador1 + 100;
                contadorgral = contadorgral + 1;


            }
            if (codigo == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ud compro producto 2");

                total = total + 150;
                contador2 = contador2 + 1;
                contadorgral = contadorgral + 1;

            }
            if (codigo == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ud compro producto 3");
                total = total + 200;
                contador3 = contador3 + 1;

                contadorgral = contadorgral + 1;



            }
            //Aca si el usuario ingresa un codigo distinto al cargado le devuelve un error 
            if (codigo > 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un codigo correcto (1,2,3)");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("La cantidad de ventas del Producto 1 fueron: " + contador1.ToString() + " El total de la venta del mismo: " + acumulador1);

        Console.WriteLine("El total de ventas es: " + total);
        prom = total / contadorgral;
        Console.WriteLine("el Promdio gral. es: " + prom);
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");

        decimal porcentaje1 = (contador1 / contadorgral) * 100;
        decimal porcentaje2 = (contador2 / contadorgral) * 100;
        decimal porcentaje3 = (contador3 / contadorgral) * 100;


        Console.WriteLine("Porcentaje 1: "+ porcentaje1);


        Console.WriteLine(porcentaje2);

        Console.WriteLine(porcentaje3);




        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estas dividiendo dos números enteros y c# lo toma como una división entera. Por lo tanto, ya que el dividendo es menor que el divisor es lógico que salga 0.

Debes convertirlos antes a double,al menos uno de los dos.

decimal porcentaje2 = (contador2 / (double)contadorgral) * 100;

Saludos

Comment: Mil gracias David por despejarme la duda! No contemple lo de los enteros. Saludos !!!

Answer (score 0):

como bien dice David el problema es con los enteros y me gustaría recomendarte algunas mejoras en tu código, como usar un switch, además que uses interpolación de cadenas, para que así la sintaxis sea más fluida. Saludos :D
int codigo = 1;
            decimal prom = 0;
            **decimal total = 0;
            decimal contadorgral = 0;**
            int contador1 = 0;
            int contador2 = 0;
            int contador3 = 0;

```
        int acumulador1 = 0;

        while (codigo != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingresar codigo: ");
            Console.WriteLine("(Presione 0 para finalizar la venta)");
            codigo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            **switch (codigo)**
            {
                **case 1:**
                    Console.WriteLine("Ud compro producto 1");
                    total += 100;
                    contador1 += 1;
                    acumulador1 += 100;
                    contadorgral += 1;
                    break;
                **case 2:**
                    Console.WriteLine("Ud compro producto 2");
                    total += 150;
                    contador2 += 1;
                    contadorgral += 1;
                    break;

                **case 3:**
                    Console.WriteLine("Ud compro producto 3");
                    total += 200;
                    contador3 = contador3 + 1;
                    contadorgral += 1;
                    break;

                **case 0: break;**

                **default:**
                    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese un codigo correcto (1,2,3)");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Clear();
                    break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(**$"La cantidad de ventas del Producto 1 fueron: {contador1.ToString()} \nEl total de la venta del mismo: {acumulador1}"**);

        Console.WriteLine($"El total de ventas es: {total}");
        prom = total / contadorgral;
        Console.WriteLine($"el Promdio gral. es: {prom}");
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");

        decimal porcentaje1 = (contador1 / contadorgral) * 100;
        decimal porcentaje2 = (contador2 / contadorgral) * 100;
        decimal porcentaje3 = (contador3 / contadorgral) * 100;


        Console.WriteLine($"Porcentaje 1: {porcentaje1}");

        Console.WriteLine(porcentaje2);

        Console.WriteLine(porcentaje3);

        Console.ReadLine();
```